# Efficient iteration through AD Group Membership

Tags: performance, powershell

I'm just going to five straight in with what I have, the scenario is a little too complex to explain off the mark.

**XML config:**

```
  <Groups>
    <Group priority="1" name="testGroup1" profile="testProfile1"/>
    <Group priority="2" name="testGroup2" profile="testProfile2"/>
    <Group priority="3" name="testGroup3" profile="testProfile3"/>
    <Group priority="4" name="testGroup4" profile="testProfile4"/>
  </Groups>
```

**Powershell:**

```
$userProfileHash = [ordered]@{}
# Itterate through groups
foreach ($group in ($homeNode.ApplicationMethod | ? {$_.id -eq "adgroup"}).Groups.Group | Sort-Object $_.priority) {
  # Get group members, Itterate through them
  Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.name | ForEach-Object {
    # Add to ordered hash
    try {
      $userProfileHash.Add($($_.samaccountname),$group.profile)
    } catch {#don't want to see errors, there may be many}
  }
}
```

**Now I'll to to explain:**

To protect against a user being a member of more than 1 of the defined groups. I sort the groups by priority (in the foreach expression) and then use the hashtable rule that the key must be unique.

This ensures that each user is only added once and that they will be assigned the profile of the group they appeared in first.

I don't really like this approach, but it was the quickest of the approaches I tried: 5 Seconds with 1100 test users.

**Question:**

How can I speed up this code? 
(there may be tens of thousands of users when this is in production)

Answer (score 0):

Hash table operations are very efficient, and if you're getting a lot of errors due to duplicate adds you might be better off eliminating the error handling.  If you sort the priorities in descending order then you can do this:

```
$userProfileHash[$_.samaccountname] = $group.profile
```

and eliminate the Try/Catch.  Duplicate memberships will just get overwritten and the last entry written for each user will be the highest priority group profile they belong to.

Edit: the original command I posted used the += operator.  That's not correct for this application, and I've corrected the code.